# There is no straightline in $C\setminus\{3i\}$ which is mappeed onto a straight line in C by f(True/false)

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\displaystyle f \colon \Bbb C\setminus \{3i\} \to \Bbb C$ be defined by $$f(z)=\frac{z-i}{iz+3}.$$ which of the following statement is true ?

1) f map circles in $C\setminus\{3i\}$ onto circles in C

2)There is no straightline in $C\setminus\{3i\}$ which is mappeed onto a straight line in C by f

My attempts :
Möbius transformation maps circles to circles ..as $C\setminus\{3i\}$ is connected,,as continous image of connected  is connected,,so option 1 is 
trues,...i don't know the option 2,,,pliz help me,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{z-i}{iz+3}=-i+\frac{2}{z-3i}
$$
If $z-3i$ is bounded away from $0$, $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @ robjohn,,im not getting  can u elaborate more ?

Comment: ok @robjohn,,as f is bounded  but straight line is unbounded,,so there will be no onto map...Am i right ?

Comment: @lomberlego: that is the main idea behind the hint, yes. Any line not passing through $3i$, will be mapped to a circle (passing through $-i$), not a line.

Comment: thanks  alot @robjohn